# facebook/twitter integration in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am facing a problem with facebook/twitter integration in cocos2d-x. I don't know how to do the facebook/twitter integration in cocos2d-x. If any one knows about this please help me.

Is it possible to implement facebook/twitter integration in cocos2d-x?

If at all possible, what happens when its ported to android/ios/etc. Will it function correctly?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a simple library to connect Java and Objective C with C++ (Cocos2dx). You can search for any tutorial for Facebook SDK integration in the required platform and simply send and receive message from C++ using my library. I have also written a complete Wiki to use this library, please have a look.

Library Source Page : https://github.com/aajiwani/EasyNDK-for-cocos2dx

Wiki Page : http://cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/EasyNDK

Comment: Consider using EasyNDK ported for cocos2d-x 3.x: https://github.com/alfonsocejudo/EasyNDK-for-cocos2dx3

Answer (score 0):

You could use the official SDKs on both platforms. Create a common C++ interface, one each for FB & Twitter, with response callbacks. Let's call the FB version "FacebookInterface.h" for now. You could then create "FacebookInterface-android.cpp" which uses the JNI to hook up with the Facebook Android SDK, and return its results back through the JNI to your C++ code. You would need to add this cpp file to your jni/Android.mk.

You could then create a "FacebookInterface-ios.mm", which you include in Xcode for your iOS build. That file would implement the header functions, and use the Facebook iOS SDK. Since that file would be a *.mm Objective-C++ file, you can interface with the FB iOS SDK if it's written in Objc.

The benefit to this is that you're using official SDKs, rather than C++ offshoots. You also get the benefit of those SDKs using higher level libraries that implement multi-threading themselves, so you don't have to mess around with pthreads and libcurl in C++.

The downside is that you have to mess with the Android JNI, but I promise you that once you figure out the nitpicky details of how to use it, it's really not that bad at all.

To make matters a little easier, you might consider unifying your interfaces at certain points. For example, your login interface might be the same between FB and Twitter. It either succeeds or it doesn't.  You might want to define an interface function that allows you to receive the response status (OK or Error), the FB access token. But then you might also want a similar function with an extra parameter for the Twitter secret key.  Both avenues lead to the same result - the user can log in, and you either get back success or failure. The SDKs should be able to handle that graphically, and then your interface would want to handle various cases like when the user closes the SDK pop up dialogs with or without a valid token, etc.  You'd also want all of your FB/Twitter api calls to route through this interface somehow, for the purpose of receiving status messages in case the call fails, so you can handle that in your C++ code.

It's a somewhat daunting task, but can certainly be broken down into pieces. The worst part is probably the Android JNI. It's not fun, but it's not the worst thing in the world.